# Using base assignment operator to rewrite only part of struct

Tags: c++, inheritance

let's say I want to wrap `Object` with some extra id for orm purposes by inheritance(that's why i cant use composition):

```
struct Object
{
    int someData;
};
struct WrappedObject : Object
{
    int id;
};
```

Is it safe to rewrite only `Object`'s part of `WrapperObject` by using it's base assignment operator? Ex

```
//scenario 1:
WrapperObject obj = /*somehow initialized*/;
Object newData = /*somehow obtained*/;
static_cast<Object&>(obj) = newData; //shouldn't touch id part

//scenario 2:
struct SomeGetter
{
    Object& get()
    {
        return wrapped;
    }
    (...)
private:
    WrappedObject wrapped;
};
(...)
SomeGetter getter = /*somehow initialized*/
Object newData = /*somehow obtained*/;
getter.get() = newData; //shouldn't touch id part
```